# Is there overhead using PHP Doc comments vs regular comments?

Tags: php, comments, micro-optimization

I read that when the PHP lexer parses the php and encounters a doccomment, that it stores the contents of that comments as metadata.  So I would assume this might have a slight overhead compared to using regular comments in non-doccomment format?

Regular comment...

```
<?php

/*
some text
/*
// more comments

?>
```

doccomment...

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Kenneth Davis
 * @copyright 2011
 * @filename Exception.class.php
*/
?>
```

Comment: No, I really don't think the standard PHP parser does anything special with doccomment comments. They are ignored the same way as normal comments are …

Comment: I wonder why you are asking this question, anyway? Pure interest or do you have some kind of "micro-optimization" in mind? If the latter one: i bet, the bottleneck is somewhere else in your application.

Comment: @Adam Wagner aPress ProPHP book is where I read about it, it is how the doc comments builds documentation

Comment: Thanks!  I've been out of php-land for sometime, but Phil's answer does ring a bell now.  It's always good to have references though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the difference is so small that it doesn't matter.  But to answer your question, there *is* a difference in runtimes.  To test this, I've generated two php files, each with 50000 classes, and each weighing in at exactly 4288896 bytes.

Here's the template I used for the docblock version:

```
/**
 * My Docblock
 */
class MyClass%s {}
```

and here's the version with no true docblock (without the two * at the
beginning, `ReflectionClass::getDocComment()` did not find the comment):

```
/*-
 * My Docblock
 */
class MyClass%s {}
```

The full script to generate the php files is here: https://gist.github.com/1268179

To see any noticable difference in time, I had to run each through php *10 times*, like so:

```
time yes docblock.php | head -n 10 | xargs -n 1 php
```

**Here's the outcome:**

with docblocks:

```
xargs -n 1 php  2.22s user 0.63s system 99% cpu 2.873 total
```

without docblocks:

```
xargs -n 1 php  2.16s user 0.63s system 99% cpu 2.813 total
```

Running this several times, seemed to yield consistent faster (barely) times for
the no docblock version.

To sum it up, that's about 0.00012 milliseconds per docblock that php keeps
track of (if I did my math right there).

Comment: But it's 120 *million* femtoseconds!

Comment: @JohnFlatness +1 :) sometimes that little extra speed is exactly what you need!

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be noticeable but was something worth knowing in the long run, thanks for the test

Answer (score 4):

The only reference to PHPDoc comments as anything other than ignored text is in [`ReflectionClass::getDocComment()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php).

I don't know if this means PHPDoc comments incur any overhead during normal parsing but doubt it makes any difference anyway. As harald mentions above, this kind of micro-optimisation would likely yield little to no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!

While it might not make cpu difference it adds to memory usage, as it is available from `ReflectionClass::getDocComment()` call as pointed in @Phil answer.

Since php 5.5 versions, with opcache, there is even option to disable doccomments:

```
opcache.save_comments = false;
```

This might lessen mem usage, but **be warned** through, as it might break some libraries, as per php docs:

> If disabled, all documentation comments will be discarded from the opcode cache to reduce the size of the optimised code. Disabling this configuration directive may break applications and frameworks that rely on comment parsing for annotations, including Doctrine, Zend Framework 2 and PHPUnit.

I've made similar test as in [Adam Wagner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682222/133408) answer:

With docblock:

```
/**
* My Docblock
*/
class MyClass%s {}
```

MEM:  **26.75 MB**
PEAK: **29 MB**

With `//` comments:

```
///
// My Docblock
///
class MyClass%s {}
```

MEM:  **25.25 MB**
PEAK: **27.5 MB**

Bu with 2.4kb doc comments results are more meaningfull:

MEM:  **63 MB**
PEAK: **101.25 MB**

vs

MEM:  **25.25 MB**
PEAK: **63.5 MB**

Test script generator:

```
<?php

$template = <<<'T'
/**
 * My Docblock
 */
class MyClass%s {}

T;
$template2 = <<<'T'
///
// My Docblock
///
class MyClass%s {}

T;
$header = <<<'T'
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) { 
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'); 

    $bytes = max($bytes, 0); 
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024)); 
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1); 

    $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);

    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow]; 
} 
function show()
{
    echo 'MEM:  ' . formatBytes(memory_get_usage(true)) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'PEAK: ' . formatBytes(memory_get_peak_usage(true)) . PHP_EOL;
}
T;
$one = "<?php\n$header";
$two = "<?php\n$header";
for($i = 0;$i < 50000;$i++)
{
    $one .= sprintf($template, $i);
    $two .= sprintf($template2, $i);
}
$one .= "show();";
$two .= "show();";

file_put_contents('one.php', $one);
file_put_contents('two.php', $two);
```